# Getting all the nodes from Python AST that correspond to a particular variable with a given name

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Consider the code below:

```
1 | x = 20
2 | 
3 | def f():
4 |     x = 0
5 |     for x in range(10):
6 |         x += 10
7 |     return x
8 | f()
9 |
10| for x in range(10):
11|     pass
12| x += 1
13| print(x)
```

The value of `x` after execution of the code above is `10`. Now, how can I get all the nodes with class `Name` whose `id`s are `x` and refer to the `x` that's being used in lines 1, 10, 12 and 13?

In other words, the `x` inside of `f` is different from the rest of the `x`s. Is it possible to get their AST nodes, having only the script and script's AST while not executing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When walking the AST tree, track the context; start with a global context, then as you encounter `FunctionDef` or `ClassDef` or `Lambda` nodes, record that context as a stack (pop the stack again when exiting the relevant node).

You can then simply only look at `Name` nodes in the global context. You can track `global` identifiers too (I'd use a set per stack level).

Using a [`NodeVisitor` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor):

```
import ast

class GlobalUseCollector(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # track context name and set of names marked as `global`
        self.context = [('global', ())]

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        self.context.append(('function', set()))
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.context.pop()

    # treat coroutines the same way
    visit_AsyncFunctionDef = visit_FunctionDef

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        self.context.append(('class', ()))
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.context.pop()

    def visit_Lambda(self, node):
        # lambdas are just functions, albeit with no statements, so no assignments
        self.context.append(('function', ()))
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.context.pop()

    def visit_Global(self, node):
        assert self.context[-1][0] == 'function'
        self.context[-1][1].update(node.names)

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        ctx, g = self.context[-1]
        if node.id == self.name and (ctx == 'global' or node.id in g):
            print('{} used at line {}'.format(node.id, node.lineno))
```

Demo (given the AST tree for your sample code in `t`):

```
>>> GlobalUseCollector('x').visit(t)
x used at line 1
x used at line 10
x used at line 12
x used at line 13
```

And using `global x` in a function:

```
>>> u = ast.parse('''\
... x = 20
...
... def g():
...     global x
...     x = 0
...     for x in range(10):
...         x += 10
...     return x
...
... g()
... for x in range(10):
...     pass
... x += 1
... print(x)
... ''')
>>> GlobalUseCollector('x').visit(u)
x used at line 1
x used at line 5
x used at line 6
x used at line 7
x used at line 8
x used at line 11
x used at line 13
x used at line 14
```

Comment: In Python 3.5+ you also should define `visit_AsyncFunctionDef(self, node)` for `async def` functions.

Comment: @pahaz an alias would be enough I think: `visit_AsyncFuncDef = visit_FuncDef`