# find all usages of certain methods and functions in a python package

Tags: python-3.x, reference

Given a package of python that have certain modules, I want to find all the usages of the methods and functions defined in the package. I am thinking something like pycharms [find usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-usages-in-the-current-file.html), in which given a function or method it shows you all the lines, from which this method/function was called.

Let's say my package has a lot of modules and I want to look for the usages of the functions and methods defined in `module_x`.
Using `inspect` and `dir` I can find all the callables defined in `module_x`

```py
import inspect

callables = [method_name for method_name in dir(module)
             if callable(getattr(module, method_name))]

module_inspected = inspect.getmodule(module)
module_file = module_inspected.__file__

module_x_callables = []

for name, member in inspect.getmembers(module):
    # to see if the definitions are defined/imported in the member_file that we are looking    
    if name in callables: 
        module_x_callables.append(member)
        member_file = inspect.getmodule(member).__file__
        # print('{}: {},{}'.format(name, member, callable(member)))
        print('{}'.format(name))
        print('{}'.format(member))
        #        print('parent: {}'.format(inspect.getmodule(member)))
        print('member_file: {}'.format(member_file))
        if member_file == module_file:
            source, line_no = inspect.findsource(member)
            print(line_no)
        print('\n')
```

Note: Methods inside classes will not be captured by this approach, but never mind. Let's say that I want to find all the usages of functions defined in `module_x`.

My question is: how can I scan the other modules in the package and see if they are using any of the defs in `module_x`, and if they are, return me the line numbers.

I tried to use `ast`, walking the tree and trying to find all the `ast.Call`. This actually returns me all the calls, but I don't know how to check if this returns all the results that are defined in `module_x`. Even more, I was thinking to use regex, but for example there could be two functions called `test_func` in two different modules. Using this approach, how do I know which one I am calling?

```py
string_code = open(file,'r').read()
tree = ast.parse(string_code)
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    #print(node)
    if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
        print('call')
        print(ast.dump(node))
        print(inspect.getmodule(node))
        print(func.value)
        print(func.attr)
        print('\n')
```

So, in conclusion, my question is: how can I explore a file or a module and find all the usages and the line number of functions and methods defined in `module_x`.
Thank you ;)

Comment: Why limit yourself to callables? All you need to resolve is if a name was imported from your module, or is used as an attribute on an imported module object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just edited my question a little bit, I think I was not precise enough. I want to find the lines where the functions/methods are called.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I would suggest looking at [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope). In particular, there is a [`.find_occurrences()`](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/library.rst#rope-contrib-findit) function which you may want to look closely at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to care about names that were actually imported into the module you are currently inspecting. Note that there are few complications here:

- Imported names are available from other modules to import from the current module; `import foo` in the module `bar` makes `bar.foo` available from the outside. So `from bar import foo` is really the same thing as `import foo`.
- Any object can be stored in a list, a tuple, become an attribute on another object, be stored in a dictionary, assigned to an alternative name, and can be referenced dynamically. E.g. an imported attribute stored in a list, referenced by index:

  ```
  import foo
  spam = [foo.bar]
  spam[0]()
  ```

  calls the `foo.bar` object. Tracking some of these uses through AST analysis can be done, but Python is a highly dynamic language and you'll soon run into limitations. You can't know what `spam[0] = random.choice([foo.bar, foo.baz])` will produce with any certainty, for example.
- With the use of the `global` and `nonlocal` statements, nested function scopes can alter the names in parent scopes. So a contrived function like:

  ```
  def bar():
      global foo
      import foo
  ```

  would import the module `foo` and add it to the global namespace, but only when `bar()` is called. Tracking this is difficult, as you need to track when `bar()` is actually called. This could even happen outside of the current module (`import weirdmodule; weirdmodule.bar()`).

If you ignore those complications, and focus only on the use of the names used in `import` statements, then you need to track `Import` and `ImportFrom` nodes, and track scopes (so you know if a local name masks a global, or if an imported name was imported into a local scope). You then look for `Name(..., Load)` nodes that reference the imported names.

I've covered tracking scopes before, see [Getting all the nodes from Python AST that correspond to a particular variable with a given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166571/getting-all-the-nodes-from-python-ast-that-correspond-to-a-particular-variable-w/43166653#43166653). For this operation we can simplify this to a stack of dictionaries (encapsulated in a [`collections.ChainMap()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)), and add imports:

```
import ast
from collections import ChainMap
from types import MappingProxyType as readonlydict


class ModuleUseCollector(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, modulename, package=''):
        self.modulename = modulename
        # used to resolve from ... import ... references
        self.package = package
        self.modulepackage, _, self.modulestem = modulename.rpartition('.')
        # track scope namespaces, with a mapping of imported names (bound name to original)
        # If a name references None it is used for a different purpose in that scope
        # and so masks a name in the global namespace.
        self.scopes = ChainMap()
        self.used_at = []  # list of (name, alias, line) entries

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        self.scopes = self.scopes.new_child()
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.scopes = self.scopes.parents

    def visit_Lambda(self, node):
        # lambdas are just functions, albeit with no statements
        self.visit_Function(node)

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        # class scope is a special local scope that is re-purposed to form
        # the class attributes. By using a read-only dict proxy here this code
        # we can expect an exception when a class body contains an import 
        # statement or uses names that'd mask an imported name.
        self.scopes = self.scopes.new_child(readonlydict({}))
        self.generic_visit(node)
        self.scopes = self.scopes.parents

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        self.scopes.update({
            a.asname or a.name: a.name
            for a in node.names
            if a.name == self.modulename
        })

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        # resolve relative imports; from . import <name>, from ..<name> import <name>
        source = node.module  # can be None
        if node.level:
            package = self.package
            if node.level > 1:
                # go up levels as needed
                package = '.'.join(self.package.split('.')[:-(node.level - 1)])
            source = f'{package}.{source}' if source else package
        if self.modulename == source:
            # names imported from our target module
            self.scopes.update({
                a.asname or a.name: f'{self.modulename}.{a.name}'
                for a in node.names
            })
        elif self.modulepackage and self.modulepackage == source:
            # from package import module import, where package.module is what we want
            self.scopes.update({
                a.asname or a.name: self.modulename
                for a in node.names
                if a.name == self.modulestem
            })

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node.ctx, ast.Load):
            # store or del operation, means the name is masked in the current scope
            try:
                self.scopes[node.id] = None
            except TypeError:
                # class scope, which we made read-only. These names can't mask
                # anything so just ignore these.
                pass
            return
        # find scope this name was defined in, starting at the current scope
        imported_name = self.scopes.get(node.id)
        if imported_name is None:
            return
        self.used_at.append((imported_name, node.id, node.lineno))
```

Now, given a module name `foo.bar` and the following source code file from a module in the `foo` package:

```
from .bar import name1 as namealias1
from foo import bar as modalias1

def loremipsum(dolor):
    return namealias1(dolor)

def sitamet():
    from foo.bar import consectetur

    modalias1 = 'something else'
    consectetur(modalias1)

class Adipiscing:
    def elit_nam(self):
        return modalias1.name2(self)
```

you can parse the above and extract all `foo.bar` references with:

```
>>> collector = ModuleUseCollector('foo.bar', 'foo')
>>> collector.visit(ast.parse(source))
>>> for name, alias, line in collector.used_at:
...     print(f'{name} ({alias}) used on line {line}')
...
foo.bar.name1 (namealias1) used on line 5
foo.bar.consectetur (consectetur) used on line 11
foo.bar (modalias1) used on line 15
```

Note that the `modalias1` name in the `sitamet` scope is not seen as an actual reference to the imported module, as it is being used as a local name instead.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava: a string with the source code of a module.